# Watching a Samba share for modifications from Linux

Tags: linux, samba, notifications

I'm trying to monitor a remote Windows Share for changes (the server can be an actual Windows machine or a Linux machine with Samba server). AFAIK the SMB protocol supports a kind of event-based notification:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj216044.aspx

And I can find it implemented server-side in Samba in the `change_notify` option in `smb.conf`.

My question is: how can I watch for such events from the client side from a Linux machine? I'd like to setup something that works in a fashion similar to `inotifywait` and be notified with an event when the content of files on the share changes, or when files are created, deleted or moved.

Comment: After 9 years we are still stuck on this issue, but there is interest on the subject. [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/896055/) 2022 article from LWN.

Answer (score 3):

**As 2022** I think using `systemd` path descriptor can work also with SAMBA share.
You have to create a `path` descriptor and a classical `service` descriptor, that runs something when triggered by the path:

```
# Path descriptor

[Unit]
Description=Watch a file this may work also with directory but is untested
Wants=<your_sevice>.service

[Path]
# 
PathModified=/path/to/file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And a `service` descriptor triggerd by the path:

```
[Unit]
Description=Do something when path changes

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/program

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As [Using systemd path](https://www.putorius.net/systemd-path-units.html), path descriptors supports other kind of options.

**Old answer**
An idea is to use Inotify on linux to monitor changing on filesystem.

As SAMBA 3.0.23 (http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_3.0_Features_added/changed), the protocol now support Inotify, server site, to notify compatible client of filesystem changing.

But, as https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/4/7/129, seems that actually CIFS client does not support correctly Inotify.

Comment: It was my first idea, but in fact it doesn't work. I've already verified inotify does not receive events for remote Samba changes.